# How can I shrink a CheckButton's icon sizes in Godot?

Tags: godot

### Background

I am making a `CheckButton` for toggling sound in my game. I have created an on and off icon for this purpose. I have two other `Button`s in a `VBoxContainer` with this `CheckButton`, whose icons are the same size as the icons for my `CheckButton`.

For the regular `Button`s, I was able to check the "Expand Icon" option to make the icons shrink to fit the size of the button.

[image: Expand Icon]

### Problem

However, the same does not appear to work for the `CheckButton`. For that, I had to override the "icons" in the theme overrides. As far as I can tell, the "Expand Icon" option does not affect these icons.

[image]

This results in the following undesirable behavior. All of these icons' backing files are the same size, but only the `CheckButton` (the speaker button at the top) is not shrinking.

[image]

I could easily make the icons just smaller, but that feels like a cop-out. Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing any setting. The icons of the `CheckButton` are not meant to scale with the button. They are meant to have a consistent size for all buttons.

*I'm not a fan of not idempotent buttons, and I'd push against anything that can lead to an confusion between state and action, however…*

For what you want, I'd suggest to use `Button`s and have code to change the `icon`.

*By the way, are you not making these icons huge to begin with? You say cop-out, I say optimization.*